# Connecting to database from prometheus_exporter

Tags: postgresql, environment-variables, prometheus, grafana

To collect Postgres metrics in prometheus, postgres_exporter is used. Containerization is not used, everything is done natively. Hardware metrics are collected in a prometheus through a job. To collect database metrics, I need to connect the prometheus_exporter to the database. Tell me how to configure the connection to the database. postgres_exporter has no configuration files. Is it possible to do this via environment variables?

prometheus.yml:

```
scrape_configs:
     - job_name: postgresql
        static_configs:
          - targets: ['xx.xx.xx.xx:9187']
            labels:
              alias: postgres
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DATA_SOURCE_NAME="postgresql://user:password@host:port/dbname?sslmode=disable"
Here at the end dbname is must to avoid error.
For my case I found it is ok now.

```
DATA_SOURCE_NAME="postgresql://grafana:p@host:192.168.1.100/postgres?sslmode=disable"
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to do this via environment variables?

Yes, it is possible. Here is the list of supported variables: https://github.com/prometheus-community/postgres_exporter#environment-variables

> How to configure the connection to the database

A simple example to launch from console:

```sh
DATA_SOURCE_NAME="user=postgres host=database.example.com" postgres_exporter
```

or

```sh
DATA_SOURCE_NAME="postgresql://user:password@host:port/dbname" postgres_exporter
```

If you installed the exporter from distribution packages, there's probably a `systemd` unit file to run it as a service:

```sh
# systemctl cat prometheus-postgres-exporter
# /lib/systemd/system/prometheus-postgres-exporter.service

[Unit]
Description=Prometheus PostgreSQL Exporter
Wants=network-online.target

[Service]
User=postgres
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/postgres-exporter $OPTIONS

# You can place environment variables in this file ⤋
EnvironmentFile=/etc/default/prometheus-postgres-exporter

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Should I put 
DATA_SOURCE_NAME="user=postgres host=database.example.com" postgres_exporter
into
[SERVICE] section?

Comment: @MarinaVinograd No, that was an example for running it manually. Look into the unit file I shared, there is `EnvironmentFile` option. Each environment variable that you put into that file will be given to whatever is executed by `ExecStart`. The unit file is usually readable by any user and because of that saving the database password there isn't the best idea. While nothing stops you from restricting access to the `EnvironmentFile` with sensitive data.

Comment: ts=2021-12-16T07:48:47.778Z caller=log.go:168 level=error err="Error opening connection to database (could not parse DATA_SOURCE_NAME): pq: password authentication failed fo

Comment: @MarinaVinograd try this format: `DATA_SOURCE_NAME="postgresql://user:password@host:port/dbname"`